# PHP & Docker: echo not logging error into docker logs

Tags: php, docker

I'm currently working in a Word press application. The application is failing in one of the methods when it tries to insert into a database. However, when I log the errors nothing is being displayed on the Docker logs.

Its really hard to debug without being able to log into the server.

```
<?php

namespace StatCollector;

function drools_request($data, $uid) {
  try {
    $db = _get_db();
    $insertion = $db->insert("requests", [
      "uid" => $uid,
      "data" => json_encode($data),
    ]);
    error_log(print_r($insertion,true));
    if( $insertion === false ) {
      throw new \Exception('Error writing to the database: ');
    }
  }
  catch(\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error writing to the database: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
  }
}
```

Here im trying to `error_log(print_r($insertion,true));` without success, also `echo 'Error writing to the database: '` but nothing is being logged into the server. How do I log into the server?

Why is the exception not being `catch`? This has been a nightmare.

Comment: Have you checked  error logs in the Docker container? Or do you have the log directories mounted to the host?

Comment: Yes, I checked the error logs but I don't see none of the things I'm logging. I also don't see any errors in the Wp Engine server